# How can I test push notifications using Testcafe

Tags: android, testing, push-notification, automated-tests, testcafe

My organisation is looking at implementing 2 step authentication using push notifications sent to a mobile app on Android or IOS and I am struggling to automate the associated scenarios within our Testcafe testsuite, which include

- enabling 2SA and connecting the mobile device via QR code scan from the web page and push confirmation
- Login, where push notification is sent to the mobile device automatically after success username/password authentication
- disabling 2SA via an automatically sent push notification to the mobile device

Is it possible to automate these scenarios using Testcafe, maybe using some mobile emulator or 'catching' the notifications at the API? To my knowledge, Testcafe is foremost targeted at browser testing and can also do API calls, but not consuming API messages without an associated call.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean mobile push notifications (not web push notifications via [Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API)), there is no way TestCafe can access them since these notifications are native.

Comment: how about using Push API? Or [Web Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)

Comment: Service Workers are used for interacting with the [Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API). TestCafe has already taken steps to support the Service Workers feature, but some Web APIs which rely on it may still not work fully. I created the issue to track progress on this: [Support Push API](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/2513).